# Thymeleaf add custom data attribute with message resource value

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a requirement where I need to insert the value to custom data tag using thymeleaf. The code for doing it using

```
  data-th-attr="${data-custom=#messages.msg('test')}"
```

as  well as

```
  th:attr="data-custom=${#messages.msg('test')}"
```

I am unable to get the value in both the cases.

ultimately the parsing should be like data-custom="test"

here test is key for the value test in a properties file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the

```
 data-th-attr="data-custom=#{test}"
```

or By using

```
 th:attr="data-custom=#{test}"
```

helped me out, here test is the key for the value in message resource the issue was with the intellij IDEA IDE, it was having a bug that was showing me an unnecessary error.

Answer (score 1):

Use th:attr="data-custom=#{key.for.message}" ,  this should work.
then after parsing the Expression, 
data-custom="value.for.message"